# Should we use different server for automation scripts

Tags: jenkins, server, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation

This is a not related to code fix, but a general approach for test automation.

I have a test automation written in javascript which runs perfectly on my machine as well as my local jenkins.

Now, i want to use my company's server(centOS) and jenkins so that it is accessible to everyone in my organization. 
Issue: nodejs version in company's server need update to run my automation, but server team wont do it since they are not sure if any other functionality used be other teams may start to break because of the upgrade.

Have you faced this situation. Do you have different servers for core code and automation scripts. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex situation that really depends on many variables. I would recommend using an agent that contains the proper version of Nodejs. With this solution you can leave the current build server how it is but you can also use the exact version of node you need. This will require an extra server/VM with the Jenkins slave software but this will remove the need to change the master server.

The solution my company went with is using Jenkins 2.x with Declarative pipelines and ephemeral Docker containers for builds. This allows you to use any Docker image such as [the official Node image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/). You can pin a version and build it with that. With this there is no need to worry about the version on the server. Jenkins Master doesn't even need to *actually build*.